# jenkins - infrastructure provisioning

Tags: jenkins

I've just finished setting up my Jenkins server but there seems to be one glaring problem that I can't find an answer to.

Shouldn't the Jenkins environment be an exact clone of  the production environment to make it effective? None of the tutorials i've read mention this fact at all. So how do people deal with this fact? especially if they are using a single Jenkins instance for multiple projects that may be running on different infrastructure?

I can imagine puppet or chef might help here but wouldn't you be constantly re-provisioning the jenkins server for different projects. sounds pretty dangerous to me.

The best solution to me seems to be to not run the test on the Jenkins server itself but to spin up a clone of the production environment and run the tests on that? But I can't find a single solitary tutorial on how this could be done on EC2 for example.

Sorry if this is a bit of a rambling question. So how does everyone else deal with ensuring an exact replica of the production environment for Jenkins to run tests on? This includes database migrations as well now that I think about it.

Thanks.

UPDATE: 
A few of the answers given seem to concern compiled languages like java or objective-c. In those situations I can see the logic of having the tests be plaform agnostic. I should have been more specific and mentioned that I use Jenkins for LAMP stack testing. So in that situation the infrastructure is as much a component that needs testing as anything else.Seeing as having PHP5.3 on one machine is enough to break a project that requires PHP5.4 for example.

Comment: Depends what you're testing.  If it's anything other than end-to-end/system tests, your tests should be written to be invariant of the environment.

Comment: This point is really helpful. I've updated the question a bit to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another approach you can consider.

With [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), you can create completely virtual environment that simulates your production. This is especially useful, when you want to test many environments (production, single node env, different OS, different DB) but you don't have enough "bare metal" machines.

You define proper vagrant environment. Next in Jenkins test item you setup proper machines, and execute tests on created vagrant environment.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins also supports a Master/Slave system (see [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) for details).

The jenkins slave itself does not need much configuration and could run on your production system replica, as it also does not need much configuration it should not influence your production clone significantly.

Your master would then just delegate the jobs (like your acceptance tests) to your slave. In that way you could also setup different production environments (like different OS, different DBs etc.) by just setting up a Jenkins slave for every configuration you need.

Comment: @StephenReid: IMO, the answer below that mentions Vagrant is a better approach than this.  With VMs (as supplied via Vagrant), you get guaranteed isolation and reproducible environments.

Comment: The vagrant answer came after I voted as correct. But I think both are valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Jenkins to check the quality of your code, compile it, run unit tests, package it, deploy it and maybe run some integration tests.

Given the nature of all those tasks, it is probably best that your Jenkins environment is NOT like your production environment. For example, you don't want your production environment to have your compiler installed (for many reasons, security to name one).

So, Jenkins is a development environment, and the fact that is doesn't exactly match your production environment should not be a concern to you.

However, I understand that perhaps you want to deploy your packages to a production-like or even production-clone environment to run some specific tests or tasks of your software lifecycle, but in my opinion that issue is beyond jenkins and concerns only the "deployment" phase of your lifecycle (ie. it's not a "Jenkins" issue, but an infrastructure issue that you should think about with a more general approach, and then simply tell jenkins where to deploy).

Comment: This is a really good point and I think you've helped me understand an important factor in the setup. I've updated the question to better outline why I think this is important.

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't think it's about compiled versus interpreted languages. For example in PHP you could be using Composer to resolve dependencies, but you don't want it installed in production.  If you want to see how your code reacts in different environment setups, the master/slave answer is perfectly valid. But if you really want to emulate production conditions, I think you should deploy to a separate environment where no development tools are installed. Otherwise something could be "working ok" because you happen to have a development library installed and you wouldn't notice.

Comment: These are all really good points. I think deploying to another environment seems to be the consensus. I guess i'm just surprised that 99.99% of the tutorials i've read don't mention how to handle this. They all seem to rely on the production environment being close enough to the jenkins environment. Seems like an essential point to me... but what do I know.